# BizTalk map does not update between deployments

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2009, biztalk-deployment, btdf

I am developing against a BizTalk 2009 environment. I am using BizTalk Deployment Framework (BTDF) to deploy my solution to the server. The problem I am facing is that when I tweak any aspect of my maps, the changes are not reflected in the BizTalk message body or output messages I use for testing. For instance, removing a link to a mapped element still shows the data being mapped from source to destination as if nothing has changed.

Between each deployment, the BTDF uninstalls the application, re-GAC's the assemblies, installs the application, and then bounces the host application. Ever so often BizTalk essentially catches up to my map version and it is working without issue until I make another tweak.

Is it possible that BizTalk is caching the map in a way that I cannot refresh?

Comment: Where is the map being used? In an orchestration or on a port?

Answer (score 2):

Are you making your map changes in the BizTalk Mapper, or an XSLT?

Visual Studio does not recognise changes in an XSLT as requiring a re-build of the assembly.  You would need to explicitly perform a "Rebuild" of the Map assembly in order to see these sort of mapping changes apply.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am only making changes inside of Visual Studio using the designer to edit the btm file. If I test the map within Visual Studio I can see my changes working as expected.

Comment: I have found the belt and braces approach of rebuilding before using BTDF to redeploy ensures all changes go through.

Answer (score 0):

Are you building your dll's for deployment on your development machine?

Then remember that version of the map from GAC will take priority over your local map from visual studio.

I was many times cought by map dll taken from GAC instead of local folder.

Hope it helps